# #Sql Comparing data of one table to that of select query result

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have table 1 with A,B,C,D,E column and the result of select query after combining the table 2 and table 3 is A, D column(few values as compare to table 1) Say view 1.

Now I need to run another query if value of column A,D of table 1  is in resulted view. this new query also have where conditions and combining two tables

Could anyone please let me know the best way out?

Example
**Table1**

```
A              B        C   D

Fruit       Orange      1   3

Vegetable   Onion      89   3

Fruit       Mango      83   22

Fruit       Banana      3   2

Vegetable   Beans     382   2
```

**View1**

```
A             B     
Fruit       Orange      
Fruit       Banana      
Vegetable   Beans
```

**Final output**

```
A              B      C  D

Fruit       Orange    1  3

Fruit       Banana    3  2

Vegetable   Beans   382  2
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hope example data may give you idea what is expected

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    view1.a,
    view1.b,
    table1.c,
    table1.d
FROM
    table1
    JOIN (
    --select query of your view
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            your_view
    ) view1 ON
        table1.a = view1.a
    AND
        table1.b = view1.b;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the `inner join` between your table and view.
`Inner join` will find the matches of column `A & B` in both tables.

```
  select table1.*
    from table 1
    inner join view1
    on table1.a = view1.a 
    and table1.b = view1.b;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried this befor itself but it is not satisfying my where clause..as I have millions of records in table

Comment: I have updated the where clause and it worked. Thank you

Comment: If the answer helped you to solve your problem, you can accept it as answer and/or upvote it. Thank you.